# Firewall source and destination IP validation

Tags: network, penetration-test, attacks, appsec

For an external firewall interface, why is it a good idea to validate that the source IP address was initiated from an internal IP, or why it originated from an external IP? If, hypothetically, the firewall was not looking for this information, what security concerns exist?

Comment: It is all about concept of firewall. You don't want people from internet to spoof as one of your internal IP to roams freely inside your intranet.

Comment: So, from an attacker perspective the following would be possible ? if i send a packet to the firewall originating externally, and set the Sender IP to be an internal IP address, I would be able to flood the internal HOST device ?

Comment: Check out this question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131084/firewall-blocking-ip-spoofing#comment244243_131084

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing.   Assume the filtering as part of most packet-filter firewall.